# Python function return the content a .py file

Tags: python

I have some python files, .py, each has several dictionaries to store some constant data. The data here will never change. I use dictionary in .py file, so I can import them later easily. Example of a file:

```
car = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}
driver = {
  "name": "Elon",
  "age": 51
}
```

I want to write a function to take a param and return the content of the corresponding .py file. What's the best way to do it? Do I just convert the .py file to bytes in the function and convert it back to .py file in the outside?

Comment: you're probably looking for the JSON format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you need is JSON files.
It is a format to store structured data in key/value style like but in files, while dictionaries are data structures stored in main memory.

Python offers simple function to handle JSON and make conversion to and from dictionaries.

`import json`

insert this in your code and take a look to official python docs here https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those are in `data.py`

Then write another script to import those variables

```
from data import car, driver

print(car, driver)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your project has the following structure:

```
my_project
|-- __init__.py
|-- data.py
|-- main.py
```

The usual way to do this is to import the variables from the file (submodule). Your `main.py` should look like this:

```py
from data import car

def my_function():
    print(car)
```